# c strings vs string class syntax with class member functions

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm converting this header file from using C++ string class to using c strings (character arrays).

I'm having difficulty with the syntax.  I understand that passing a pointer to an array of char should work in the same way as passing a string.

I've been struggling to get this to compile for some hours and it is time to reach out for some help. the compiler errors are inline.    Any help would be appreciated.  I'm stepping away for a couple of hours.  I can post the main function as well, but I think the problem is starting here.

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED
#define EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED
#endif // EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED

using namespace std;


class Employee
{
private:
    int id;             // employee ID
    char *name;        // employee name
    double hourlyPay;   // pay per hour
    int numDeps;        // number of dependents
    int type;           // employee type

public:
    //Employee();  // Default Constructor


    Employee(int initId,const char *name,
             double initHourlyPay ,
             int initNumDeps , int initType);  // Constructor

    bool set(int newId, char newName[], double newHourlyPay,
             int newNumDeps, int newType);

    int getID();     // returns the employee ID
    char getName();   // returns Employee name
    int getDeps();      // returns number of dependents
    float getRate();    // returns rate of pay
    int getType();      // returns employee type

};

int Employee::getType(){
    return type;
}

float Employee::getRate(){

    return hourlyPay;

}

int Employee::getDeps(){

    return numDeps;
}

int Employee::getID(){

    return id;
}
```

This is where it stops.

```
|23|error: default argument missing for parameter 2 of 'Employee::Employee(int, char, double, int, int)'|
|62|error: prototype for 'Employee::Employee(int, char*, double, int, int)' does not match any in class 'Employee'|
|10|error: candidates are: Employee::Employee(const Employee&)|






char* Employee::getName(){       
    return name;
}

Employee::Employee( int initId, const char *name,
                    double initHourlyPay,
                    int initNumDeps, int initType )
{
    bool status = set( initId, initName, initHourlyPay,
                       initNumDeps, initType );

    if ( !status )
        {
            id = 0;
            name = NULL;
            hourlyPay = 0.0;
            numDeps = 0;
            type = 0;
        }
}

bool Employee::set( int newId, char newName[20], double newHourlyPay,
                    int newNumDeps, int newType )
{
    bool status = false;

    if ( newId > 0 && newHourlyPay > 0 && newNumDeps >= 0 &&
         newType >= 0 && newType <= 1 )
        {
            status = true;
            id = newId;
            name = newName;
            hourlyPay = newHourlyPay;
            numDeps = newNumDeps;
            type = newType;
        }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Your include guard isn't doing much. The purpose is to prevent multiple definitions of the class, but the class definition is there regardless of whether `EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED` is defined.

Comment: I think the error message means you have a place where you're calling the `Employee` constructor with a `char` rather than `char*`.

Comment: Oh 'dat' careless handling of `char*`... Like Barmar said, likely on another implementation when you're actually using this class, you're likely calling it with a `char` instead of `char*` argument 2.

Comment: It seems odd to be changing data types _from_ `std::string` _to_ `char*`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::string::c_str()` if you need to pass a `const char *` to some function that takes a character pointer?

Comment: Why would you change from `std::string` to `char *`? This would just cause problems e.g. with memory management? You just pass a pointer, but who controls the memory the pointer points to?

Comment: The program was initially written with strings, but this assignment is intended to give me a sense of how to handle c-strings (among other things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one problem:

```
Employee::Employee( int initId, const char *name, // <-- name
                    double initHourlyPay,
                    int initNumDeps, int initType )
{
    bool status = set( initId, initName, initHourlyPay, // <-- initName
                       initNumDeps, initType );
```

I've added a couple of comments in line with the code; 
the comment `<-- initName` shows where you try to pass a variable named
`initName` to the `set` function, but there is no variable declared with
that name; instead, you have a variable named `name` four lines earlier.

I think this is also not recommended:

```
bool Employee::set( int newId, char newName[20], double newHourlyPay,
                    int newNumDeps, int newType )
```

Why specify the exact length of the string? It doesn't occur anywhere else.
The same function parameter is given as `char newName[]`
in the function declaration.
In fact, inside the `set` function you have this:

```
            name = newName;
```

so I would rather see the parameter declared as `char* newName` in both places
(function declaration and function definition). It doesn't make any
difference to the compiler, but passing `char newName[]` *looks* and *feels*
like you mean only to give the function temporary access to the array of `char`
(either to copy something from it, or to write something to it, or both),
but actually it's making that array part of the object by storing
its address in a member variable.

And that brings to mind another anomaly in this program, which is that
you store the member variable `name` as a `char*`, but the
address is passed into the constructor as a `const char*`.
This may cause additional compilation problems.
I'd recommend either use `char*` in all places where you pass this string
into the function, if you want to copy the pointer and be able to
modify the contents of the string later,
or use `const char*` for the function parameter in the constructor
and in the `set` function, and either store it in a `const char*`
or make a new copy of the string (which you can store either as a
`const char*` or as a `char*`).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I kept trying different things and my code was just getting worse.  I followed the recommendation of using char * everywhere, and I got rid the initName vs newName inconsistency.  The header is compiling and I'm  back to debugging the main function.   I WILL master this!